# GROUP BY from inner SELECT suquery is ignored in column sum

Tags: mysql

I have following query

```
SELECT YEAR(T.date), MONTH(T.date), T.production, T.lineID, SUM(rework + scrap)
FROM
   (SELECT MAX(positionID), date, production, lineID
    FROM productionPerPosition
    WHERE lineID = 2
    AND date BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-01-31'
    GROUP BY date) AS T
INNER JOIN linePosition lp ON lp.lineID = T.lineID
INNER JOIN fttErrorType fet ON fet.positionID = lp.positionID
INNER JOIN fttData fd ON fd.errorID = fet.errorID
                        AND fd.date = T.date
GROUP BY YEAR(T.date), MONTH(T.date)
```

which gives this result

[image]

Now, I would like to group these results by year and month to get sum of production and sum of last column. I've tried this query

```
SELECT YEAR(T.date), MONTH(T.date), SUM(T.production), T.lineID, SUM(rework + scrap)
FROM
   (SELECT MAX(positionID), date, production, lineID
    FROM productionPerPosition
    WHERE lineID = 2
    AND date BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-01-31'
    GROUP BY date) AS T
INNER JOIN linePosition lp ON lp.lineID = T.lineID
INNER JOIN fttErrorType fet ON fet.positionID = lp.positionID
INNER JOIN fttData fd ON fd.errorID = fet.errorID
                        AND fd.date = T.date
GROUP BY YEAR(T.date), MONTH(T.date)
```

Which gives me

[image]

Here production sum is wrong! It seems that GROUP BY from 7th line in first query is ignored.

Any idea how could I get needed result?

Edit: In inner SELECT I have separate production for several different positions (positionID) but I'm using only production from position that has highest positionID

Comment: well you are using a non standard group by query (as allowed by older versions of mysql). That sometimes gives wierd results

Comment: What is the standard way of group by?

Comment: too long for a comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Answer (score 0):

Has explained in e4c5 comment, you have to add all the unaggregated fields to your GROUP BY. I made it in the inner SELECT and in the main SELECT:

```
SELECT YEAR(T.date), MONTH(T.date), SUM(T.production), T.lineID, SUM(rework + scrap)
FROM
   (SELECT MAX(positionID), date, production, lineID
    FROM productionPerPosition
    WHERE lineID = 2
    AND date BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-01-31'
    GROUP BY date, production, lineID) AS T
INNER JOIN linePosition lp ON lp.lineID = T.lineID
INNER JOIN fttErrorType fet ON fet.positionID = lp.positionID
INNER JOIN fttData fd ON fd.errorID = fet.errorID
                        AND fd.date = T.date
GROUP BY YEAR(T.date), MONTH(T.date), T.lineID
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same result with this modified query

Comment: Where are your rework and scrap fields in the subquery? I think you have to expose them and group them too.

Comment: they are present only in fttData table

Answer (score 0):

Group has missing grouping columns that why it is resulting in some unexpected result

```
 SELECT YEAR(T.date), MONTH(T.date), SUM(T.production), T.lineID, SUM(rework + scrap)
    FROM
       (SELECT MAX(positionID), date, production, lineID
        FROM productionPerPosition
        WHERE lineID = 2
        AND date BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-01-31'
        GROUP BY date, production, lineID) AS T
    INNER JOIN linePosition lp ON lp.lineID = T.lineID
    INNER JOIN fttErrorType fet ON fet.positionID = lp.positionID
    INNER JOIN fttData fd ON fd.errorID = fet.errorID
                            AND fd.date = T.date
    GROUP BY YEAR(T.date), MONTH(T.date), T.lineID
```

Comment: still getting the same results